# make a subdirectory show the content of a subdomain in nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, subdomain, subdirectory, proxypass

I want to handle this:

`blog.example.com => example.com/blog`

`blog.example.com/xxx => example.com/blog/xxx`

in both samples there is nothing in blog subdirectory, and the code which should handle the blog is in subdomain. and just i want to show the url as showed above.

so. i want to forward(redirect without changing url) a subdirectory to subdomain.

is there any nginx configuration to do that?

Comment: did any answer solve your question?  if yes, please accept&&upvote, if no, please clarify what's missing.

Comment: did any answer solve your question? if yes, please accept&&upvote, if no, please clarify what's missing. – cnst Jul 11 '16 at 17:11

Answer (score 0):

You could have the following in your NGINX configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 $scheme://example.com/blog$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /blog/ {
        <your code goes here>
    }
}
```

This takes any incoming requests to `blog.example.com` and redirects to `example.com/blog` along with the requested URI eg. `blog.example.com/latest` would redirect to `example.com/blog/latest`

Comment: many many thanks for your answer. i will try it. and how about `example.com` or `example.com/xxx` ? these routes will work fine as before?

Comment: Yes, they'll work fine. The only issue is that the URL will change on the client side

Answer (score 0):

```
location = /blog {
    return 302 /blog/;
}
location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/;
}
```

Note that the `/` in [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) is very important (without it the `/blog` part won't be stripped out in the request to upstream).

Some further details on the rationale of two independent `location` statements are available at https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass/562850#562850.

Comment: @parisssss, did this answer solve your question?  if yes, please accept&&upvote, if no, please clarify what's missing.